# multi replace text with different values phpstorm

Tags: php, regex, phpstorm

Say you have:

`www.example.co.uk/about
 www.example.co.uk/help
 www.example.co.uk/goats`

etc (but multiplied by several hundred). In phpstorm, or any other editor for that matter, how can i turn the selection to:

`'/about' => '/',
 '/help' => '/',
 '/goats' => '/',`

Tried with find and replace by no luck

Comment: You can use notepad++

Comment: So what is the problem with replacing `^www.example.co.uk` with nothing?

Comment: Please clarify: do all of your urls have the same prefix that you want to remove? In that case, find-and-replace really should work.

Comment: Find: `(?m)^.+(?=/)` Replace with nothing.

Comment: Sorry, second set of code was incorrect. Adjusted

Comment: `'/about' => '/',` is that a literal, or what do you mean?

Comment: hmm, search for [\/.+](https://regex101.com/r/wV3kI3/1) and replace with `/` ?

Comment: @user35745, you really have to give us more here. Replacing `\w+$` might work for you, but we need more example so we can prevent false positives.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex that will match the last parts of URLs after the last `/` and replace the strings as required:

```
(?m)^.*?(\/[^\/\n]+)$
```

Replace with `'$1' => '/',`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tZ9gJ8/1)

The regex matches

- `(?m)` - forces `^` to match the beginning of a line
- `^` - the beginning of a line
- `.*?` - 0 or more characters other than a newline as few as possible
- `(\/[^\/\n]+)` - literal `/` and 1 or more characters other than `/` or a newline
- `$`  end of line